# How to get double entries in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

| kartikel | kattribut |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 124 |
| 2 | 123 |
| 2 | 128 |
| 2 | 129 |

Now i want to get the doublettes ordered by article

I tried:

```
select kArtikel, kAttribut, COUNT(*)
from tArtikelAttribut
group by kArtikel, kAttribut
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Now i get:

| kartikel | kattribut |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 123 |

The attribute "123" can set for each article. So i just have to get the information, if the attribute is double set for one article.

Does anyone know, how to do this?

Comment: What's the output that you want?

Comment: Use DISTINCT in the SELECT clause of the SELECT statement

Comment: Your query would not produce those two rows since `2, 123` occurs only once. Your question is not clear.

Comment: @SQLpro, how would SELECT DISTINCT help? The GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: The above query will not return the specified result (when having the given table data.) Why don't sample data and result match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want your result to be:

```
kartikel    kattribut
1           123
1           123
```

In this case duplicate is kartikel+kattribut, my guess is that those are char columns so I propose:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#testtable') is not null drop table #testtable

create table #testtable (id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, kartikel varchar(5), kattribut varchar(5))
insert into #testtable (kartikel, kattribut)
values ('1', '123'), ('1', '123'), ('1', '124'), ('2', '123'), ('2', '128'), ('2', '129') 

select
    id,
    kartikel,
    kattribut
from #testtable
where kartikel+kattribut in (
    select
        kartikel+kattribut as DistinctValue
    from #testtable
    group by kartikel+kattribut
    having COUNT(*) >1
    )
order by kartikel
```

I added id column to table, it's always good to have it, you can remove row by id if you want to clear duplicates.

Comment: `kartikel+kattribut` is a very dangerous code. `'1' + '123'`  = `'11' + '23'`.

Comment: @jarlh I agree with you, but like I wrote, my guess that 'kartikel' and 'kattribut' are varchar and not numbers. But, in theory, there could be same combinations and in that case i would use ''kartikel+'whateverstrangeword'+kattribut''

Comment: I'd do EXISTS instead of IN, and check each condition separately.